# Save Actual Response time for a Process from Start to Complete in summary report(jtl) in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have jmeter test plan in which I create a workflow which transitions statuses like Not Started to In Progress to Completed. 
The problem I am having is how I can measure how long it took for workflow status from the time of creation to it get completed? Since we are logging the response time of api calls only. 
Is there a way we can extract this info and also add it to the summary (jtl reports?) I was thinking if I could do it from beanshell post processor where I have the wait time calculated and also checking the status of workflow and I could write to the summary result (jtl). How can I do this?

I have the test plan set up something like this:

```
Thread Group
 - Create Workflow API call
 - WhileLoop(checking on a flag set by beanshell post processor)
   - Wait for 5seconds 
   - Check for timeout using JSR223 sampler(java)(don't want test to run inevitably if something goes wrong so want to break the loop after a fixed amount of time)
   - Get Workflow status API call
   - Beanshell post processor to check the response from above call to see if status is Completed or wait time has exceeded. In either of these cases I set the while loop flag false if not repeat the loop wait for 5 seconds and so on.
```

For the test itself it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use transaction controller to measure the time taken. Please check the reference;-

> The [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) generates an additional sample which
>   measures the overall time taken to perform the nested test elements.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Sunny. I didn't realize transaction controller also adds the sample to the summary report. :)